NFS and ACLs in a Kerberos context on Rocky Linux 8.9
We're running a Rocky Linux 8.9 (so, essentially RHEL 8.9) shop and I've been tasked with investigating ACLs on filesystems mounted via NFS. We're using FreeIPA/IdM as well.
I've set up a test machine, enrolled it in IdM, exported an NFS share, and mounted it locally, but the ACL part seems to be lacking:
[root@example ~]# cat /etc/exports
/export/ *(rw,acl,no_root_squash)

[root@example ~]# mount | grep /export
localhost:/export on /mnt type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp6,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=::1,local_lock=none,addr=::1)

[root@example ~]# cd /mnt/
[root@example mnt]# touch testfile
[root@example mnt]# getfacl testfile
# file: testfile
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

[root@example mnt]# setfacl -m u:user:r testfile 
setfacl: testfile: Operation not supported


A couple of questions:

Is it correctly understood that I should be using getfacl and setfacl rather than their nfs4_ equivalents since both the client and server are Linux/POSIX?
Do I need idmapd? I have a service called nfs-idmapd running successfully.
I read somewhere that sec=sys should be replaced with seckrb5 when mounting.

UPDATE:
I investigated some more, and had a minor breakthrough: nfsv4_set*acl work fine on the NFS share as long as one uses numeric UIDs or GIDs. It's the coupling to IdM/Kerberos that's causing trouble.

I cracked the nut. I'm not entirely sure what went wrong, but it could be a combination of configuration and firewall rules. The following script works:
#!/bin/bash

# This script presumes a RL 8.4+ "Minimal Install" ready machine which has 
# been prepped for OTP install in IPA.

dnf upgrade -y

dnf install -y ipa-client
ipa-client-install -U -w myonetimepassword

dnf install -y nfs-utils

cat <<EOF > /etc/exports 
/export *(rw,sec=sys,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async)
EOF

systemctl enable --now nfs-idmapd.service
systemctl enable --now nfs-server.service

exportfs -arv

firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=nfs
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=rpc-bind
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=mountd
firewall-cmd --reload

echo "Now is a good time to reboot."


Then to mount (from the same machine, or another) simply
mount hostname.example.com:/export /mnt

And then use nfs4_setfacl and nfs4_getfacl on the client (make sure the nfs4-acl-tools package is installed):
$ nfs4_getfacl testfile 
# file: testfile
A::OWNER@:rwatTcCy
A::GROUP@:rwatcy
A::EVERYONE@:rtcy

$ nfs4_setfacl -a A::user@domain.local:rw testfile 
ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 bo bo 0 May  6 12:42 testfile

$ nfs4_getfacl testfile 
# file: testfile
A::OWNER@:rwatTcCy
D::1050400001:wa
A::1050400001:rtcy
A::GROUP@:rwatcy
A::EVERYONE@:rtcy


Support for POSIX ACLs over NFS v4.2 was added in RHEL 8.4. This is documented in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/8.4_release_notes/index#enhancement_file-systems-and-storage at the end of this section (bug https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1888214):
Support for user extended attributes through the NFSv4.2 protocol
This update adds NFSv4.2 client-side and server-side support for user extended
attributes (RFC 8276).
This includes the following protocol extensions:

New operations:

GETXATTR - Get an extended attribute of a file
SETXATTR - Set an extended attribute of a file
LISTXATTRS - List extended attributes of a file
REMOVEXATTR - Remove an extended attribute of a file


New error codes:

NFS4ERR_NOXATTR - xattr does not exist
NFS4ERR_XATTR2BIG - xattr value is too big


New attribute:

xattr_support - Per-fs read-only attribute used to determine if xattrs are
supported.  When set to True, the object's file system supports extended
attributes.




The regular set/getfacl uses extended attributes, which are indeed part of NFSv4.2, as described in the answer from @abbra https://serverfault.com/a/1158690/127530. However, xattr support is not ACLs.
To use ACLs over NFSv4 you should use the nfs4_set/getfacl commands, which are part of the nfs4-acl-tools package.

But the nfs4_setfacl still gives an error.

Operation not supported? Does the server supports ACLs at all?

Rocky Linux (and Alma Linux) are continuations of CentOS which is forked from Red Hat Enterprise Linux where ACLs are not available for NFSv4. The same is true for your Rocky Linux 8 system and it is still true in RHEL, Rocky, Alma 9.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23230
There are utilities that can be installed via the nfs4-acl-tools package that work in a similar manner. The commands are called nfs4_setfacl and `nfs4_getfacl' and allow setting ACLs for groups. I have used the GID below.
df -h | grep export

192.168.1.100:/mnt/export  3.6T  3.1T  401G  89% /mnt/export

[root@rocky-linux export]# touch zfile
[root@rocky-linux export]# nfs4_getfacl zfile
# file: zfile
A::OWNER@:rwatTcCy
A::GROUP@:rtcy
A::EVERYONE@:rtcy
[root@rocky-linux export]# nfs4_setfacl -a A:g:1004:rw zfile
[root@rocky-linux export]# nfs4_getfacl zfile
# file: zfile
A::OWNER@:rwatTcCy
A::GROUP@:rtcy
A:g:1004:rtcy
A::EVERYONE@:rtcy

More information is here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3426621

Thanks! Not to question your knowledge, but the link is for RHEL 4 which is ancient, is there one for a more recent distro?

@bolind RHEL 4 doesn't appear anywhere on the page. The Bugzilla link does but the page itself is for Red Hat Enterprise Linux all version. The getfacl and setfacl commands aren't available with NFSv4 on RHEL-based systems but there is another utility which works in a similar manner. See my updated answer for more info.

Is the rocky-linux host the NFS client or the NFS server?

@bolind Why would I provide an example of it on the server when that isn't relevant to what you are trying to do? If that were the server, then the getfactl and setfacl commands would work and there wouldn't be any need for the other commands because it wouldn't be an NFS export.

There could be plenty of reasons, and since the export and mount point are identical, there is no way to tell...

@bolind No, there couldn't. That wouldn't make any sense for the reasons that I've given. You are just asserting it to be true when it doesn't line up with what's going on. The mount point having the same name is neither here nor there. The output of df -h makes it rather evident that it's the client. It's not that hard to ascertain this.
